# dpkg: error processing package install-info

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, imagemagick

I tried installing `imagemagick` package by 
`sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

I'm getting the following error now, how to fix it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
imagemagick is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu2.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (6.4.90.dfsg.1-1build1) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: TESSDATA_PREFIX: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please add contents of `/etc/environment` file to the question.

Comment: i found somewhere the answer, its fixed - i have posted the answer.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst.bad
```

Alternatively a shorter command:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst{,.bad}
```

Fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks this helps solved my problem when i tried to install mdadm

Comment: Yep. This solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Currently trying to install 19 from 17 and couldn't upgrade, this has allowed me to proceed with (at least, so far) apt-get update. Thanks! +1

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem but can you explain the problem and solution.

Comment: Thanks a bunch; this worked perfectly for me. What's puzzling is that the date stamp on the /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst file is 10/10/2019. Why is this causing a problem only now? What just occurred to me is that I upgraded to Mint 20.2 (Uma) from 20.1 (Ulyssa) a couple of days ago, and this MIGHT be the first update I'm applying since that. Coincidence? Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: when I was upgrade ubuntu 18.04 to  20.  run sudo apt full-upgrade error.