# sudo apt-get autoremove error

Tags: command-line

Every time I try to run `sudo apt-get autoremove`, I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up install-info (6.7.0.dfsg.2-5) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: JAVA_HOME: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does that help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069702/dpkg-error-processing-package-install-info ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a partially installed package. `sudo apt install -f` should fix it. If not have a look at the advice here: [How to fix broken or missing packages](https://linuxhint.com/apt_get_fix_missing_broken_packages/)

Comment: "sudo apt install -f" isn't working for me