# having trouble installing zoom

Tags: zoom-meeting

I am trying to get Zoom working on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. I am following directions on
https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-zoom-client-on-ubuntu-debian/
and i have typed:

`$ sudo apt -y install wget`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wget is already the newest version (1.19.4-1ubuntu2.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 246 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 3: /etc/environment: aws_access_key_id: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have some very hard feelings about this and the other stackexchange sites. I am hoping you guys are going to prove my stackExchange phobia wrong.

How do I get to the next step in the installing zoom instructions? BTW, I am not on my AWS server, just my ubuntu laptop.

Comment: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1069702/1438484) appears to have a very similar error to the one you posted. Can you try the answer there, and see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: Nmath, following your council I ran update and upgrade but got this: richb201@richb201-XPS-13-9370:~$ sudo apt upgrade
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Comment: The problem here is corrupted apt post-install procedure. Please share contents of `/etc/environment` file to find `aws_access_key_id` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You are making this harder than it needs to be. Zoom can be easily installed via snap.

You probably already have snap installed, but in case you don't, run:

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

If you already have snap (typical), just run:

```bsh
sudo snap install zoom-client
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that I already have zoom client installed. snap "zoom-client" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'